# Apache returns the perl script source instead of execute the script when the request comes from chrome

Tags: apache-2.2, perl, firefox, awstats, google-chrome

I've just finish to install awstats on my web server, and it runs fine using firefox. But when I try to open the awstats page with chrome, the perl source script is downloaded (instead of being executed). it seems the MIME requested by Chrome gave a different behavior compared to Chrome. Any idea ?

Interesting part of the Apache configuration file:

```
<Directory "/var/www/cryptis-https-root/admin-awstats">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews  ExecCGI
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from X.Y
</Directory>

Alias /awstatsclasses "/var/www/awstats/wwwroot/classes/"
Alias /awstatscss "/var/www/awstats/wwwroot/css/"
Alias /awstatsicons "/var/www/awstats/wwwroot/icon/"
ScriptAlias /admin-awstats/ "/var/www/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/"

<Directory "/var/www/awstats/wwwroot">
  Options None ExecCGI
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from X.Y
</Directory>
```

I've tried to add the following line in the apache configuration file but it has no effect:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .pl
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/">
  Options +ExecCGI
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from X.Y
</Directory>

Alias /awstatsclasses "/var/www/awstats/wwwroot/classes/"
Alias /awstatscss "/var/www/awstats/wwwroot/css/"
Alias /awstatsicons "/var/www/awstats/wwwroot/icon/"
ScriptAlias /admin-awstats/ "/var/www/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/"

<Directory "/var/www/awstats/wwwroot">
  Options None
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from X.Y
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you need to turn on CGI scripts. To do that, you need to run command `a2enmod cgi`.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity. Are you sure that it is echoing the Perl source code in Chrome? Or is it that chrome is unable to render the response? The latter would be caused by missing MIME type.

Comment: No, apache really sends the whole Perl source code (hopefully critical code in it)